# mysql - join select data from two different fields in table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables:

- **friends** table (`UserID`, `FriendID`) and
- **users** table (`UserID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`).

I'm trying to do one SQL query to join and pull all records that have the `UserID` or `FriendID` inside friends table equal to the user's ID but pull the `FirstName` and `LastName` from the other `UserID`.

For example

friends table

```
UserID = 1 | FriendID = 2
UserID = 3 | FriendID = 1
```

user table

```
UserID = 1 | FirstName = "Bob"  | LastName = "Hope"

UserID = 2 | FirstName = "John" | LastName = "Doe"

UserID = 3 | FirstName = "Bill" | LastName = "Murray"
```

If I am logged in as Bob(`UserID` = 1) trying to pull all of my friends user data (`FirstName` and `LastName`) in one query by checking if `UserID` 1 is either a `FriendID` or `UserID` inside the friends table. Then join the data for the opposite field that isn't my ID.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE userid IN ( SELECT userid FROM friends WHERE friendid = 1
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT friendid FROM firends WHERE userid = 1);
```

This will give you:

```
| USERID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME |
---------------------------------
|      2 |      John |      Doe |
|      3 |      Bill |   Murray |
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f4a9/2)

Comment: Thank you very much! Extremely detailed and love the SQL Fiddle Demo never heard of it until now.

Answer (score 1):

## If I understand your question, then this works

```
-- set the id of the logged in user
set @logged_in = 1;

-- select all the fields from the user table
select users.* from users
-- joined the friends table on the `FriendID`
inner join friends on friends.FriendID = users.UserID
-- filtered by `UserID` on friends table matching logged in user
and friends.UserID = @logged_in -- logged in id
-- union-ed with the users table
union select * from users
-- filtered by the `UserID` being the logged in user
where users.UserID = @logged_in -- logged in id
```

### Results for @logged_in = 1:

```
UserID  FirstName   LastName
2       John        Doe
1       Bob         Hope
```

### Results for @logged_in = 2:

```
UserID  FirstName   LastName
2       John        Doe
```

### Test Database Create Code:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `friends`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `friends` (
  `UserID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FriendID` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `friends`
--

INSERT INTO `friends` (`UserID`, `FriendID`) VALUES
(1, 2),
(3, 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `UserID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`UserID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`) VALUES
(1, 'Bob', 'Hope'),
(2, 'John', 'Doe'),
(3, 'Bill', 'Murray');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select b.uid as userid, a.firstname, a.lastname 
from user a
Inner join (select friendid as uid from friends where userid=:currentUser
Union select userid as uid from friends where friendid=:currentUser) b
```

On a phone, so may need syntax tweaks.

An optimiser may suggest a different join strategy based on your real data